# How to Fix Missing Organization Profile Dropdown in Contribution Form Settings

Tags: civicontribute, profile

I'm working on my first install of CiviCRM. So far it's been a fairly smooth process. I'm at the point of creating a form to register members (as we are a 501c6). I created a contribution form, and I want to require that users contribute on behalf of an organization - as this is a registration for membership.

However, the dropdown menu to select which profile to use isn't there. I see where it should be, but it doesn't show up. This is my first form of this type, so it's entirely possible I just missed something simple, but I've tried everything I can think of. I've even disabled the CSS in case that was somehow hiding the dropdown.

[image: Screenshot]

At this point, I can't move forward with the registration is it requires me to put in an Org Profile but does not give me any way to select one.

Anybody experienced this problem before? Anything I can do to fix it? Because I'm stumped on this one.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I just posted this on the [old forums](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36335), but saw that they were deprecated, so I moved it over here.

Answer (score 2):

The "on behalf of" functionality uses the "On Behalf of Organization" profile which is a default/reserved profile. You should be able to find it by clicking on the *Reserved Profiles* tab in **civicrm/admin/uf/group** (or under **Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Profiles**):

[image: Reserved Profiles]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there isn't an Organization profile available.  There should be the default reserved profile "On Behalf of Organization", but you can also create your own profile and use it.  It has to be an Organization profile, with no individual fields in it.  Either copy a reserved profile and edit it, or start your own. Be sure to use only Organization and Contact fields (CiviCRM won't let you add Individual ones once you have an Organization field in there), and then you can select the profile.

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the screenshot that your site is experiencing javascript errors. You'll find an explanation of this and possible solutions here:

[Troubleshooting popups, autocompletes, or other javascript problems](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850.0.html).